# Trusted global root ca not updated with restricted internet access

Tags: windows, certificate

I have two windows machines that have restricted internet access and can only load windows updates from the internet. I wanted to check our certificate on those machines but our certificate is invalid because one certificate in the chain is missing. The "GeoTrust TLS RSA CA G1" is missing on those machines.

I thought windows updates will also update certificates. Do I need to add another rule to the firewall to another server to get certificate updates?

Comment: That particular certificate was updated in March. Any modern version of Windows would already have it. Since the machine is isolated the solution is just [install](https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm) it yourself

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah thats what I did but how can I prevent this from happening in the future? I never had such a problem with the current setup. But I am right that those certificates comes with regular windows updates right?

Comment: Trusted CA rarely change.

Comment: Any updates to any certificates would be handled through a cumulative update through a servicing stack update (SSU)